# Turning games built in FLEX into stand-alone Flash games

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-cs5

I am looking at a project where the original developer created a series of slot machine games using Flash / FLEX. Each game has a separate python script which controls the games logic, but they all share assets and actionscript via the same master Flex interface.

I am not a Flash guy, so I am trying to understand how hard it would be to split these games from this single FLEX system into stand-alone SWF games that still interact with the python scripts to control game logic.

Is this a major job that requires a lot of recoding?

Can a Flash developer simply copy the elements and logic and easily create a stand-alone SWF?

My gut says this is an easy job, but I'm not familiar enough to know.

Thank you in advance for sharing your opinion.

Comment: Without viewing code; I don't think this question is answerable.  Conceptually; it should be easy to separate out independent parts of a Flex application.  In practice it is rare that independent parts are actually coded independently.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand the Flash Platform correctly,Flash and Flex both make swf files. If you want however, you can make AIR installable applications as well from them.

Comment: sorry, it got short, I have to go